# How to connect Android phone to PC wirelessly?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ftp, android

I live in a 7-floor building with one WiFi (and more than 60 connected devices). The internet works fine in my Laptop and phone, but I can't connect them to each other using FTP or whatever like I used to do when I was living in my home.

For some reason, I can't connect any local device (192.168.x.x), not even the router!

Is there a way to make a private network wirelessly between my Laptop and my phone so I can use the FTP to transfer my files, etc.?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure they are on same network ? As you mentioned, there is /16 network, so probably it's divided into several smaller. Be sure to check network addresses, network masks and default gateway, because you should be able to communicate with devices on same network. Check also routing table on notebook, there should be at least 1 default route (0.0.0.0) to default gateway

Comment: How can I know if both devices are on same network? (they use the same WiFi)
and what do you mean by /16 network?
My local IP in the laptop is 192.168.10.133 (10 not 1), and in the phone 192.168.10.61
The gateway IP is 192.168.10.1, so does this mean they are on the same network?

Comment: Yeah, if both devices have the same default gateway, they are on same network, so you are saying that you cannot ping mobile IP from notebook right?

Comment: Exactly. When I open the Command Line in Windows 7, and type ping www.google.com (or whatever), it's fine. But when I try to ping 192.168.10.61 (my phone), or 192.168.10.1 (the router?), there is no reply. Request timed out.

How is this possible? I didn't make any changes to firewall or anything. Last week, I used the same laptop and the same phone in another place (small house), and they connect without any problems. I can access everything on my phone using FTP wirelessly.

Comment: Try `traceroute google.com`

Comment: This is really weird! I typed tracert google.com as you said, and it showed me this list:
1       192.168.10.1 (expected)
2       192.168.11.1 (what's this?)
3       192.168.4.1 (???)
4       ..................
5        .................
6        ..................

What does this mean? BTW, I cannot ping 192.168.11.1 or 4.1

Comment: Well, that means, that you are going through other other networks as well and your network administrator maybe disabled pinging between devices. The solution may be for example to use `adb`, but if you want to use it, you need to have android tools install on windows and also you need to have enabled usb debugging. If you do this, you can connect mobile to computer via USB cable and then in command prompt type `adb devices`, there should be listed your device...If so, you can use `adb push` and `adb pull` to move files to/from it, respectively.

Comment: So I can't create a private network between my PC and my phone wirelessly?
If I want to use the USB cable, I can move files normally without the need for adb etc. But I've noticed this way is not reliable.

Comment: @Sammy I'd try to install `Fing` on Android and with it check the network, I use this app a lot